# Is it possible to instruct AWS Custom Authorizers to call AWS Lambdas based on Stage Variables?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, custom-authentication

I am mapping Lambda Integrations like this on API Gateway:

```
${stageVariables.ENV_CHAR}-somelambda
```

So I can have `d-somelambda`, `s-somelambda`, etc. Several versions for environments, all simultaneous. This works fine.

**BUT**, I am using *Custom Authorizers*, and I have `d-authorizer-jwt` and `d-authorizer-apikey`.

When I deploy the API in DEV stage, it's all ok. But when I deploy to PROD stage, all lambda calls are dynamically pointing properly to `*p-lambdas*`, except the custom authorizer, which is still pointing to "d" (DEV) and calling dev backend for needed validation (it caches, but sometimes checks the database).

Please note I don't want necessarily to pass the Stage Variables like others are asking, I just want to call the correct Lambda out of a proper configuration like Integration Request offers. By having access to Stage Variables as a final way of solving this, I would need to change my approach and have a single lambda for all envs, and dynamically touch the required backend based on Stage Variables... not that good.

Tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. It works just as I described. There are some caveats:
a) You need to previously grant access to that lambda
b) You can't test the authorizer due to a UI glitch ... it doesn't ask for the StageVar so you will never reach the lambda
c) You need to deploy the API to get the Authorizers updated on a particular Stage

Cannot tell why it didn't work on my first attempt.